# Create Multiple Users from ACF Repeater Field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working with a Repeater Field where the Administrator will create a list of names and email addresses. When that list of names is saved (or updated), I would like to create new users based on the names and email addresses. Here is the code I have so far:

```
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=team_member', 'add_new_user', 10, 3);

function add_new_user( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
if(isset($value) && $value != '') {

    if( get_field('team_member') ) {
        while( has_sub_field('team_member')) {

            $user_name = strtolower( get_sub_field('member_fname') ) . '_' . strtolower( get_sub_field('member_lname') ) ;
            $pw = wp_generate_password( $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false );
            $user_email = get_sub_field('member_email_address');

    $value = wp_insert_user( array(
                'user_login' => $user_name,
                'user_pass' => $pw,
                'user_email' => $user_email
            ));

        }       
    }
}
return $value;
}
```

There are 2 problems with this code:

1. It only creates one user account for the first name on the list
2. For some odd reason, when the Options page is Saved/Updated, there are 30 new blank rows created on the options page.

Any ideas on how to make this work? Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

I've updated the code based on Aibrean's suggestions and all names in the list are being saved as a user.

```
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=team_member', 'add_new_user', 10, 3);
function add_new_user( $value, $post_id, $field ) {

if(isset($value) && $value != '') {

    if( have_rows('team_member') ) :
            while( have_rows('team_member') ) : the_row();

                $user_name = strtolower( get_sub_field('member_fname') ) . '_' . strtolower( get_sub_field('member_lname') ) ;
                $pw = wp_generate_password( $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false );
                $user_email = get_sub_field('member_email_address');

            $value = wp_insert_user( array(
                'user_login' => $user_name,
                'user_pass' => $pw,
                'user_email' => $user_email
            ));

        endwhile; 
    endif;
}

return $value;
}
```

This code successfully saves each name as a new WP User but here are the 2 problems that occurring now:

1. All but one row of the repeater field are being removed. The names on the list are gone, but the user has been created.
2. 30 additional rows are created for some reason.

Comment: Well you have two fields with the same selector (team_member). One is field and the other is sub_field. That's probably part of your problem, and also might be since it's not done with "have_rows". The way you have it now is pre v4.3.

Comment: @Aibrean thanks for the pointers. I updated the code based on your recommendations. It seems so close, but with still some major problems. What is the best way to show the updated code?

Comment: Do an edit to your post, explain what you did below the original and insert your code there.